# How to use the 0.91' 128*32 OLED by arduino pro mini?

Tags: arduino-pro-mini

I buy a OLED as picture below, I want to use https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_SSD1306 to control it. But the example of https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_SSD1306 can't be compiled. The error as the second picture below. How should I to use this OLED ?

> [image]
>
> [image]

Comment: It looks like there is more to the error message that isn't shown in your image. Instead of posting an image of text, copy and paste the error text into your question.

Comment: @josecanuc  I have add it. Could you help me ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to installing the Adafruit_SSD1306 library, you also need to install the Adafruit_GFX library, which is a dependency of the SSD1306 library.